# React Await Syntax

Tags: javascript

```
const {data: roles} = await getRoles();
```

What is the meaning of const{data: roles}? getRoles returns data from an API but I am not sure if the data is getting assigned to the data variable or roles variable.

Comment: The reason why people downvote is simply because this is explained in any basic Javascript tutorial. It would be faster to search a bit before asking a question.
We usually want people to research before asking questions, otherwise this site would be filled with thousands of similar questions.
A reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: It's simply a poorly written question. It's not a question about a programming problem but that of basic syntax, which could be answered by a small amount of research. People are expected to make a bare minimum of effort before writing a question. The title of the question has nothing to do with the problem, though that is acceptable since it's possible to not know what the true problem is, but it's not even written as a short, informative summary of the question as it's expected to be.

Answer (score 0):

It's identical to this:

```
const roles = (await getRoles()).data;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the destructuring syntax. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
Basically you get an object like this:

```
response: {
   data: ["foo"],
},
```

Which you can then "destruct" into

`const { data: roles } = response;`

where `roles` is the variable name you want to *use* instead of data.
You could also do

`const { data } = response;`

It's basically a quicker way to use data instead of doing
`response.data`